# Mantine MultiSelect integration with react-hook-form

Tags: react-hook-form, mantine

I am trying to include a Mantine MultiSelect in an react-hook-form controlled form but i struggle with the correct implication of the onCreate property. The MultiSelect should be creatable.

The code of the component is:

```
import type { SelectItem } from '@mantine/core'
import { MultiSelect } from '@mantine/core'
import { Controller, useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form'

export default function ManMultiSelect({
  name = '',
  label = '',
  data = [''],
  placeholder = '',
  disabled = false,
  searchable = false,
  nothingFound = 'Leider nichts gefunden',
  creatable = false,
}) {
  const { control } = useFormContext()

  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => (
        <MultiSelect
          placeholder={placeholder}
          label={label}
          value={value as string[]}
          onChange={onChange}
          data={data as (string | SelectItem)[]}
          disabled={disabled}
          clearable
          creatable={creatable}
          getCreateLabel={(query) => `+ Füge ${query} hinzu`}
          // onCreate={}
          searchable={searchable}
          nothingFound={nothingFound}
          className="w-full"
        />
      )}
    />
  )
}
```

the component is called via:

```
<ManMultiSelect
              name="trainings"
              label="Fortbildungen der Einrichtung"
              creatable={true}
              searchable={true}
              placeholder="Hier die erfolgreich absolvierten Fortbildungen eintragen"
              data={facilityDetails?.trainings || []}
            />
```

How can i use value and onChange correctly or implement an onCreate correctly to be able to create new values?